# Command prompt - Wait For known IP address

Tags: cmd, wait

I want to write a simple .bat file that will ping a number of IP addresses (to confirm servers are online) in turn, without me having to type "ping server name" each time

I looked at resources and those mentioning the wait command seem to all reference if the IP address in unknown

so what i would like is

Ping 10.X.X.1 
Wait 10 seconds (or however long it takes to display the standard 4 ping response) 
Ping 10.X.X.2
Wait 10 seconds (or however long it takes to display the standard 4 ping response) 
Ping 10.X.X.3

and so on

Comment: Do you have a list of server IP addresses in a file?

Answer (score 1):

so you know the addresses and are visually checking if any responds?
you should be able to use the -n option to limit ping to 4 pings per address:

```
;pingall.bat
ping -n 4 10.X.X.1
ping -n 4 10.X.X.2
ping -n 4 10.X.X.3
```

let me know if I misunderstood what you are trying to do

EDIT: 
If you have a known list of IPs you can ping them via a list:

```
for %i in (1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 11, 110) do ping -n 4 10.X.X.%i
```

If you want to ping a range of IPs use this (start, increment, end):

```
for /l %i in (1,1,254) do ping -n 4 10.X.X.%i
```

Comment: oops, typo in my first answer. there should be a space between -n and 4

Comment: This wouldn't run correctly. EITHER use `/l` OR a list. Not both.

Comment: @Stephan, works fine for me in a Win7 command prompt. I'll remove the loop solution from my answer anyway because I think the first one is more simple.

Comment: I put both solutions back to your answer, because I think, they are very elegant and useful - and at least, they were your idea.